# Preciso transformar dados de uma tabela CSV em uma tabela HTML, porém nao posso utilizar bibliotecas imports neste codigo

Tags: html, python, microsoft-excel, csv

**Um exemplo de como está os dados dentro deste CSV, são mais de 20 registros com títulos entre outras colunas e eu não posso editar ele:**

[10.1109/mcom.2014.6871677,,,"Context-aware vehicular cyber-physical systems with cloud support: architecture, challenges, and solutions","The advances in wireless communication techniques, mobile cloud computing, and context- aware technologies boost a growing interest in the design, development, and deployment of vehicular networks for emerging applications. This leads to an increasing evolutionary tendency to change from vehicular networks toward cloud-assisted context-aware vehicular cyberphysical systems. In this article, we first propose a multi-layered context-aware architecture and introduce two crucial service components, vehicular social networks and context-aware vehicular security. Then we propose an application scenario regarding the context-aware dynamic parking services by illuminating the cloud-assisted architecture and logic flow. Finally, we investigate the challenges and possible solutions, including context-aware safety hazard prediction, context-aware dynamic vehicle routing, and context-aware vehicular clouds.","Jiafu Wan,Daqiang Zhang,Dongliang Zhang,Daqiang Zhang,Dongliang Zhang,Daqiang Zhang,Shengjie Zhao,Shengjie Zhao,Laurence T. Yang,Laurence T. Yang,Laurence T. Yang,Jaime Lloret",IEEE Communications Magazine,2014]

[10.1109/tits.2022.3173944,,,Vehicle Trajectory Prediction in Connected Environments via Heterogeneous Context-Aware Graph Convolutional Networks,,"Yuhuan Lu,Weiqi Wang,Xiping Hu,Pengpeng Xu,Shengwei Zhou,Ming-cheng Cai",IEEE Transactions on Intelligent Transportation Systems,2022]

**Consegui criar a tabela com python e criar o primeiro for para verificar os índices, porém o caractere separador que estou utilizando é a virgula, e esta separando meus títulos, criando mais índices e deixando a tabela e o código uma bagunça, não consigo sair desta estaca. Detalhe, não posso utilizar nenhuma biblioteca
Queria apenas conseguir deixar estes títulos juntos e encontrar uma forma de acessar estes índices para imprimi na tabela do HTML**

```
with open('dados.csv','r',encoding='utf-8' ) as arquivo:
    linhas = arquivo.readlines()
with open('index.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as pagina:

    for linha in linhas:
        valores = linha.split(',')
        DOI = valores
        title = valores
        authors = valores    
        print(valores)


    pagina.write(f'<tr><td>{DOI}</td><td>{title}</td><td>{authors}</td></tr>\n')
```

Comment: Importante [editar sua pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/581702/70) conforme orientações deixadas lá (restaurando-a se necessário). Para evitar duplicação de orientações, o espaço de comentários foi limpo e desativado aqui, mas pode ser usado na postagem original.